# CvRect error C2661: 'CvRect::CvRect' : no overloaded function takes 4 arguments opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I create a:

```
CvRect aaaaa=CvRect(0,0,10,10);
```

but I got this error:

> error C2661: 'CvRect::CvRect' : no overloaded function takes 4 arguments

I don't undestand why i got this since it takes 4 arguments.
I'm using c++ and Opencv 2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From reading the reference guide for [CvRect](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_basic_structures.html#cvrect) it seems that it is a `struct` with no constructor. But there is a helper method named `cvRect()` that can be used to create a `CvRect`:

```
CvRect aaaaa = cvRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

the error message is clear, there is no constructor function 'CvRect::CvRect' takes 4 arguments. and in fact the constructor is no arguments.

and also, it is better

```
CvRect aaaa;
```

instead of

```
CvRect aaaa = CvRect();
```

the last one will takes one more copy constructor call.